# How to configure Eclipselink so that it returns no cache in response?

Tags: angularjs, jpa, caching, http-headers, eclipselink

I have a problem with AngularJS + EclipseLink app in IE. In every other browser this is working. When I delete an object from a list, IE Edge shows still the old list with deleted object. I have tried to kill cache in AngularJS side, but no result (`$scope.rmas = rmaService.query({cacheKill : new Date().getTime()}, function (data)`)...

I have tried to disable cache from whole Eclipselink persistence unit, no luck or it works partly. When I delete an object, it disappears from the list, but when I come back to list page, it is still there again and it is deleted from DB. Could console.logs affect like that, cause I have heard that IE doesn't like console.logs :)

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public List<Rma> findAll() {
    return super.findAll();
}
```

Comment: It would depend on how your are using JPA.  JPA EntityManagers are required to track managed entities, so it maintains a cache of everything that goes through it.  EntityManager were meant to be used as a unit of work, not to be kept around for a long time without careful consideration.  Make sure that you are closing and reobtaining EntityManagers when needed, or at least clearing them at logical points

Comment: Any idea how to add no cache to response? I am using generated code (facade-pattern) in REST-services.